# Tensorflow data transfer when running empty operations

Tags: python, tensorflow

Consider the following Tensorflow code:

```
op = tf.no_op()
sess = tf.Session()
feed_dict = ...
sess.run(op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Since `op` is an empty operation and does not depend on any other Operation, will tensorflow do the job of populating the placeholders in `feed_dict` with the specified data, or it will be able to resolve that there is no need to do the work. I guess the behavior will be the same if `op` is an empty python list or dictionary? This becomes important when `feed_dict` contains a lot of data and when this data has to be transferred between the CPU and the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow does prune the graph, removing all operations that are not needed to compute the fetched tensors, but this pruning does not apply to feeds. TensorFlow always converts the fed numpy arrays into `tensorflow::Tensor`s. This involves copying the memory from the numpy array to Tensor-owned CPU memory. No data will be copied to GPU, though. Copying to GPU requires an actual operation (that survived pruning) on GPU with this Tensor as input.